# convert x, y, zoom to long and lat (help)

Tags: maps, coordinates

I am trying to get the coordinates from one point on this but it does only give me the x and y coordinates and the zoom data too. Even though i am trying to figure out how to convert x and y to lat and long. the data that appear in this map are confusing me too much. this map gives me:

http://gis.nyc.gov/doitt/nycitymap/

Height: (static value)
width:  (static value)
minX
maxX

minY
maxY

zoom

those are the data this maps gives me for 1 specific building or place and i don't know how to convert it in lat and long. can someone help me out on this please?

Thank you so much for reading this post.

Answer (score 2):

This perhaps can help

```
public double xCoordinateToLongitude(int x, int z) {
    return x / Math.pow(2.0, z) * 360.0 - 180;
}

public double yCoordinateToLatitude(int y, int z) {
    double n = Math.PI - (2.0 * Math.PI * y) / Math.pow(2.0, z);
    return (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.sinh(n))) * -1) * 1000000 / 1000000;
}
```

(* 1000000 / 1000000 ) is for decimal approach

Answer (score 0):

[gaston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28883274/4282622) is almost correct.
His second function returns negative numbers for the top hemisphere.
So just remove the `* -1` from the last line:

```
public double xCoordinateToLongitude(int x, int z) {
    return x / Math.pow(2.0, z) * 360.0 - 180;
}

public double yCoordinateToLatitude(int y, int z) {
    double n = Math.PI - (2.0 * Math.PI * y) / Math.pow(2.0, z);
    return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.sinh(n))) * 1000000 / 1000000;
}
```